# Different types when same template argument?

Tags: d

```
struct Matrix(T, size_t row, size_t col){

  alias row Row;
  alias col Col;

  auto opBinary(string op, M)(in M m) const if(op == "*"){
    static assert(Col == M.Row, "Cannot Mix Matrices Of Different Sizes.");
    // whatever...
    return Matrix!(T, Row, M.Col)();
  }
}


void main(){


  Matrix!(double, 2, 3) m1 = Matrix!(double, 2, 3)();
  Matrix!(double, 3, 2) m2 = Matrix!(double, 3, 2)();
  Matrix!(double, 2, 2) m3 = m1 * m2;  // ERROR
// Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (m1.opBinary(m2)) of type Matrix!(double,row,col) to Matrix!(double,2,2)
}
```

Why the error and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, currently, templates are instantiated with their *argument* types, not their *parameter* types.

If you changed your return statement to:

```
return Matrix!(T, cast(int)Row, cast(int)M.Col)();
```

It will compile, because it was instantiated with `int`, not `size_t` (which is uint or ulong).

This is a long-standing bug and although he previously didn't like it, [Walter recently changed his mind](http://dfeed.kimsufi.thecybershadow.net/discussion/thread/jbv98f%2428su%241@digitalmars.com?page=4#post-jc0b1a:24t8v:241:40digitalmars.com) supporting changing this to use the parameter types. [Here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/449) is the pull request fixing this issue (it will be in the next DMD release), linking various related bugs.

Comment: so if Walter doesn't support fixing it, then he doesn't think it's a bug, right?  What reason did he give?

Comment: He was arguing that templates are always instantiated on the types of their arguments, while everyone else was essentially arguing that they're instantiated on the values of their arguments (with the majority of template arguments being types). Bug report: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3467

Comment: Clarified and added a link to the NG post.

Comment: His actual rationale was that you could easily add template specializations later without breaking existing binaries. However, "experience seems to indicate that this isn't worth it".

Comment: @Trass3r He did give that as a secondary rationale later, but his initial statements all revolved around how templates are instantiated based on their arguments' types.